# Excel VBA - Enumeration in Class

Tags: excel, vba, class, enums, enumeration

I am quite new to Class Modules.

I know how I can make an Enumeration in a Class,
but is it possible to refer to its values too?

**For example:**

```
'Class Module
Public Enum Alphabeth
A = 1
B
C
End enum
```

Let's say I made an instance called 'Alpha' of this Class,
can I then somehow refer to the value of "C" in the Enum?
Something like Alpha.myEnum.C (which should give a value of "3").

Comment: From both inside and outside the class you can refer to the Enum like this:  `Alphabeth.C`

Comment: But I cannot use the Class name with that? I was hoping I could combine Classname + Enumname + Enum, like Alpha.myEnum.C...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested VB (VBA) Enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984992/nested-vb-vba-enumeration)

Comment: @Rezzy777 I don't believe you can include the class name like you want.  Typically Enums are used as parameters or return values on methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In class module:

```
Public Enum Alphabet
    a = 1
    b
    c
End Enum

Public Property Get GetEnum(Letter As String) As Long
    Select Case Letter
        Case "a"
            GetEnum = Alphabet.a
        Case "b"
            GetEnum = Alphabet.b
        Case "c"
            GetEnum = Alphabet.c
        ' etc
    End Select
End Property
```

In a regular module:

```
Sub UseEnum()

    Dim Alphabet As clsAlphabet
    Set Alphabet = New clsAlphabet
    
    MsgBox Alphabet.GetEnum("a")

End Sub
```

**Edit:**
Found a better solucion:
In class module:

```
Public Enum Alphabet
    a = 1
    b
    c
End Enum

Public Property Get Alphabet(Letter As Alphabet) As Alphabet
    Alphabet = Letter
End Property
```

In a regular module:

```
Sub UseEnum()

    Dim Alphabet As clsAlphabet
    Set Alphabet = New clsAlphabet
    
    MsgBox Alphabet.Alphabet(a)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I meant. I actually thought using an Enum (inside a Class) would be better, but now I see it only makes everything very complex since you cannot refer to it directly. I'll try something else. Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 1):

`Enum` is not a class... It is a statement.

1. Please, copy the `Enum` declaration on top of a standard module (in the declarations area):

```
Public Enum Alphabeth
    A = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3
End Enum
```

2. Copy the next `Sub` in the same module, or an another one and run it:

```
Sub testEnumAlph()
   Debug.Print Alphabeth.A, Alphabeth.b, Alphabeth.c
End Sub
```

If write Alphabeth, intellisense will suggest the Enum members...

It will return in Immediate Window (`Ctrl + G`, being in VBE): 1 2 3...

Comment: I know it's not a Class, so it cannot be used in a Class either? Something like Class.myEnum.C?

Comment: @Rezzy777 You can, but not in the same way. You should create methods to get and let values and use them to return the `enum` members. I can show you a simple class with an example, if needed...

Comment: Thank you, but that won't be necessary anymore ;-)

Comment: @FaneDuru fyi might want to see how to define invisible [_Start] member to the `Type` definition at [Type inside class module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68834576/excel-vba-type-inside-class-module/68837805#68837805)

Comment: @T.M. I know about these invisible members. I was preparing a class example containing `Enum` with an invisible member, but OP did not say that he is interested in an example and somebody else posted one. But, I will follow the link...