# Excel VBA - Type inside Class Module

Tags: excel, vba, class

I am trying to use a Type inside a Class Module, but I keep getting several errors.
I have tried switching between "Private" and "Public", but to no avail.

Can anyone provide me an example of how to use a Type inside a Class Module?

This is what I am trying:

```
'Class "clsColor"

Private Type Colors
Red as string
Green as string
Blue as string
End Type

Private Hex as Colors
'_____________________________________________
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
Hex.Red = "FF0000"
Hex.Green = "00FF00"
Hex.Blue = "0000FF"
End Sub
```

```
'Regular Module

msgbox clsColor.Hex.Red
```

What can I do to make this Type work inside the Class Module?
Or is it better practice to create an extra Class instead of a Type?

Comment: Declare it in a standard module (public) and the class should only have a property of that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Type cannot be used in this case.  Instead use a Class:

**Class Colors**

```
Option Explicit

Public Red As String
Public Green As String
Public Blue As String
```

**Class Color**

```
Option Explicit

Private m_Colors As Colors

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
   Set m_Colors = New Colors
   m_Colors.Red = "FF0000"
   m_Colors.Green = "00FF00"
   m_Colors.Blue = "0000FF"
End Sub

Public Property Get Hex() As Colors
   Set Hex = m_Colors
End Property
```

**Form**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Test()
   Dim MyColor As Color
   Set MyColor = New Color
   Debug.Print MyColor.Hex.Red
End Sub
```

Comment: Solved the issue how to use `{object}.Hex.{color}` syntax +:) - Fyi You might be interested in my answer focussing more on the practical use of `Type` and `Enum` definitions as asked by OP ("Can anyone provide me an example of how to use a Type inside a Class Module?")

Comment: I got everything working properly now. One final question (if I may): at the bottom of class 'Color' you use "Set" to set "Hex" to "m_colors". Is this because you defined Hex as a class "Colors", and classes always need to be set? I'm pretty new to Classes, hence my question ;-)

Comment: @Rezzy777 Yes, that is correct.  Classes need to use Set.

Comment: Further readings: [MS Help: Objects and classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/) as well as Chip Pearson's classical site, here about[Classes]
(http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx) - @Rezzy777

Answer (score 2):

Brian M Stafford proposing a *two-class approach* noted: *"`Type` cannot be used in this case"* when
you want to set different *colors* as **object property** to `.Hex`, e.g. via

```
MyColor.Hex.Blue
```

> *"Can anyone provide me an example of how to use a Type inside a Class Module?"*

Instead of a successive object hierarchy, it might make calls *more fluent*, if one passes the wanted color as ►variant **argument** to `.Hex` only.

In this case you need no related class and can profit from `Type` (and `Enum`) definitions
allowing to get the wanted result e.g. via (enumerated constant)

```
MyColor.Hex(Blue)      ' or via VBA.ColorConstants: MyColor.Hex(vbBlue)
                       ' or via string input:       MyColor.Hex("Blue")
```

**Class Color - Header definitions (`Enum`, `Type`)**

```
Option Explicit

Enum ColorSynonyms
   [_Start] = -1
'equivalents to the 8 VBA.ColorConstants (vbBlack, vbRed..)
    Black
    Red
    Green
    Yellow
    Blue
    Magenta
    Cyan
    White
'---user defined constants
    Brown
    Grey
    Orange
End Enum

Private Type THexColors
        Red   As String
        Green As String
        Blue  As String
End Type

Private HexColors As THexColors
```

**Class Color** *- further code*

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    With HexColors
        .Blue = "0000FF"
        .Green = "00FF00"
        .Red = "FF0000"
    End With
End Sub

Public Property Get Hex(currColor) As String
    Select Case currColor
        Case "Red", Red, vbRed
            Hex = HexColors.Red
        Case "Green", Green, vbGreen
            Hex = HexColors.Green
        Case "Blue", Blue, vbBlue
            Hex = HexColors.Blue
        Case Else
            Hex = "Undefined!"
    End Select
End Property
```

**Example Call**

```
Private Sub Test()
    Dim MyColor    As Color
    Set MyColor = New Color
    Debug.Print "Blue", MyColor.Hex(Blue)
    
'alternatively:
    Debug.Print "Blue", MyColor.Hex(vbBlue)
    Debug.Print "Blue", MyColor.Hex("Blue")
End Sub
```

Comment: Great solution, though a bit complex for my case (I have a lot more than a few colors to work with)! But thanks anyway, I'll keep this solution in mind!

Comment: Good point, I just did! :-) I also recently got a message while trying to make a new question that 'some of my questions have not been well-received', which apparently means I asked some wrong questions I am not aware of. Do you know where I can see my not-so-well-received questions?

Comment: The best thing to do is to study [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [MCV E](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), an abbreviation for a **M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable *E*xample. - Some hints: Voting down, also known as "casting downvotes", is how the community indicates which questions and answers are least useful 
- c.f. SO's help [Vote down](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down). Always show what you tried and identify the *precise* errors you were facing.
Downvotes also reflect personal expectations and may set the bar high.